# Not including a number as a variable from user input and having it increment another variable?

Tags: java, loops, variables, increment

My programs asks the user to input integers (on a loop) until they input -99; which will then display the highest and lowest numbers of the input integers. I have a variable called count, that increments every time the user puts in a new integer, to keep track of the number of integers inputted by the user. How can I have -99 not included as one of the integers and not incrementing count?

Code:

```
//variables
        int num = 0, count = 0, high, low;
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);


        low = num;
        high = num;

        //loop

        while(num != -99){
                    System.out.print("Enter an integer, or -99 to quit: --> ");
                    num = userInput.nextInt();
                    count++;



                    if (num == -99 && count == 0)
                    { 
                        count--;
                        System.out.println("You did not enter a number");

                    } //outer if end
                    else {



                    //higher or lower
                    if(count > 0 && num > high)
                    {
                       high = num; 
                    } //inner else end
                    else if(count > 0 && num < low)
                    {
                        low = num;
                    } //inner else if end
                    else
                    {

                    } //inner else end
                    } //outer else end
    }     


        System.out.println("Largest integer entered: " + high);
        System.out.println("Smallest integer entered: " + low);
```

Comment: A simpler method would be to test `num` directly after you set it to the user input.  `if(num!=-99)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You approach is good, but you missed some points,

- your condition to find max or min is also wrong because you have to write them separately.
- User Entered any value or not, you have to decide this outside the loop.
- You have to initialize high and low with first input.
  I am trying to make some correction in your program, just changing the required part. Hope it will help you.

```html
  //variables
    int num = 0, count = 0, high =0 , low = 0;
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    //loop

    while(true){
  //Using infinite loop, we will break this as per condition.
  System.out.print("Enter an integer, or -99 to quit: --> ");
  num = userInput.nextInt();
  if(num == -99)
  {
   break;
  }
  count++;

  if(count == 1)
  {//initialize high and low by first number then update
   high = num;
   low = num;
  }
  //to check highest
  if(num > high)
  {
     high = num; 
  } 
  
  //to check smallest
  if(num < low)
  {
   low = num;
  }
  
                
}     
if (count == 0)
{//Here we check that if user enter any number or directly entered -99 
 System.out.println("You did not enter a number");
}
else
{
 System.out.println("Largest integer entered: " + high);
    System.out.println("Smallest integer entered: " + low);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This makes much more sense now!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommended the following solution :

First of all, get a number from the user before the loop.

Then check if the number is -99 or not.

You know what to do if it is.

If not, start a **do-while** loop and do the following :

1. Increment the count.
2. Update your low and high.
3. And the last statement of the loop body will get another number from the user.

The while condition after the loop body will check that the latest number entered is not -99.